# Cannot train image segmentation model with UNet

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

## My environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.6.8
- Tensorflow 1.12.0

## The problem

I made UNet to segment images by using Tensorflow. I refered [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597), and I implemented the same structure except for the output channel number (used 3 but not 2). My model seems to work well, but the loss does not converge, it is like electrocardiogram ...

I used MSE as loss function, but some websites said that MSE does not valid in UNet, so I change to use dice loss. But still, it does not work. I suspect that the network structure is bad.

## The codes

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.name_scope('input'):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 572, 572, 3], name='X')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 388, 388, 3], name='y')


# Encoding
with tf.name_scope('layer1'):
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1')
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv2')

with tf.name_scope('layer2'):
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='VALID', name='pool1')
    conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool1, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv3')
    conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv3, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv4')

with tf.name_scope('layer3'):
    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='VALID', name='pool2')
    conv5 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool2, filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv5')
    conv6 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv5, filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv6')

with tf.name_scope('layer4'):
    pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv6, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='VALID', name='pool3')
    conv7 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool3, filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv7')
    conv8 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv7, filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv8')

with tf.name_scope('layer5'):
    pool4 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv8, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='VALID', name='pool4')
    conv9 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool4, filters=1024, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv9')
    conv10 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv9, filters=1024, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv10')


#Decoding
with tf.name_scope('layer6'):
    up_conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv10, filters=512, kernel_size=2, strides=2)
    croped_conv8 = tf.image.central_crop(conv8, 7/8)
    concat1 = tf.concat([croped_conv8, up_conv1], axis=-1)
    conv11 = tf.layers.conv2d(concat1, filters=512, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv11')
    conv12 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv11, filters=512, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv12')

with tf.name_scope('layer7'):
    up_conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv12, filters=256, kernel_size=2, strides=2)
    croped_conv6 = tf.image.central_crop(conv6, 13/17)
    concat2 = tf.concat([croped_conv6, up_conv2], axis=-1)
    conv13 = tf.layers.conv2d(concat2, filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv13')
    conv14 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv13, filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv14')

with tf.name_scope('layer8'):
    up_conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv14, filters=128, kernel_size=2, strides=2)
    croped_conv4 = tf.image.central_crop(conv4, 5/7)
    concat3 = tf.concat([croped_conv4, up_conv3], axis=-1)
    conv15 = tf.layers.conv2d(concat3, filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv15')
    conv16 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv15, filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv16')

with tf.name_scope('layer8'):
    up_conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv16, filters=64, kernel_size=2, strides=2)
    croped_conv2 = tf.image.central_crop(conv2, 49/71)
    concat4 = tf.concat([croped_conv2, up_conv4], axis=-1)
    conv17 = tf.layers.conv2d(concat4, filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv17')
    conv18 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv17, filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv18')

    output = tf.layers.conv2d(conv18, filters=3, kernel_size=1, name='output')

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    dice = 2 * tf.math.reduce_sum(output*y) / (tf.math.reduce_sum(output) + tf.math.reduce_sum(y) + 1)
    loss = 1 - dice
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope('save'):
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    loss_sumary = tf.summary.scalar('ls', loss)
    filewriter = tf.summary.FileWriter('./', tf.get_default_graph())
```